# How to make PSD plot from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fft

[Here you can download the signal and python file](https://ufile.io/bpoj6nzu)

I am trying to make a psd plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('signal.csv')
fft = pd.DataFrame(np.abs(np.fft.rfft(df['1'])))   #y
n = df['0'].size
unit_freq = 1000000000 #Giga
sample_rate = 10000000000   #10 GS/s
freq_sample_fact = sample_rate/unit_freq
freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(n, 1/freq_sample_fact)       #x
fft.index = freq
fft.values[0] = 0


arfft = fft.to_numpy().T
plt.psd(arfft, 512, 0.01)


plt.xlabel('Frequenz / GHz')
plt.ylabel('Signalstärke')
plt.title('FFT')
plt.show()
```

Warning:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 7179
    line = self.plot(freqs, 10 * np.log10(pxx), **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10
```

Output:

[image]

Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: why does your `fft` variably need to be a dataframe?

Comment: It does not have to be a dataframe but in this case it is. But I transform it into an array and it still doesn't work.

Comment: based on the error message, you might have a zero in your frequency array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `psd` function does all the FFT stuff inside.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as p 
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('c:/pddata/stackoverflow_signal.csv')
dt=df.iloc[10,0]   -df.iloc[0,0]
print(f'time delta: {dt*1e5:.3f} us')  # 10 MHz sampling, if time is in seconds
data=df['1']
print(f'length of vector: {len(data)}, time = {(dt*1e2*len(data)):.3f} ms')

p.figure(figsize=(20,8))
p.subplot(211)
p.plot(data)
p.subplot(212)
p.psd(data,  2000,1/0.1);
```

See examples in the documentation: 
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/psd_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-psd-demo-py
If the time vector is given in seconds, then the sampling rate is 10 MSa/sec and the max. frequency 5 MHz.

[image]

Comment: That is more than I could ever hope for. Thank you so much.